# Passar parâmetro via jquery com href

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma tabela com links gerados automaticamente e valores sendo passados via json.

O link retorna os valores correto sendo gerados usando PHP.

```
<li>
    <a href='phpProcess/showFormDelegationPr.php?prId="+item.pr_id+"' class='link-form-delegation' id='show-form-delegation'>
        <i class='fa fa-user'></i> &nbsp; Delegar
    </a>
</li>
```

Quero passar os valores para o PHP usando jquery, mas não estou tendo sucesso.

Tentei com o código abaixo:

```
$("#consult").on("click", ".link-form-delegation", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#show-form-delegation").attr("href"),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });         
});
```

O problema é que para todas as linhas da tabela o alert mostra sempre o valor de retorno da primeira linha da tabela.

Comment: Se o problema é no retorno, deve estar do lado do servidor, não no jquery.

Comment: Fiz um teste para checar o valor de retorno sem a chamada jquery, o valor retornado pelo PHP está correto.

Answer (score 2):

[Como o Juliano referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/49015/129) tens IDs repetidas. Quando usas:

```
url: $("#show-form-delegation").attr("href"),
```

isso vai retornar o `href` do primeiro elemento com esse ID. Mesmo que haja mais, ele retorna somente o primeiro pois o ID tem de ser único.

Para contornar esse problema (que tens de resolver no lado do servidor) podes usar o `this` no elemento que recebeu o click, que presumo ser aquele que pretendes ler o `href`. Vais ter de o referênciar numa variável pois não podes passá-lo diretamente para o `.ajax()` pois ele irá ser lido noutro contexto de escopo.

Assim, penso que o que procuras é:

```
$("#consult").on("click", ".link-form-delegation", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
    // ou usar var self = this; e depois usar ": $(self).attr("href"),"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });         
});
```

Repara que no caso de também haver vários `#consult` duplicados tens de mudar isso e usar classes, ou somente `$(document).on('click', ...` para jogar pelo seguro.

Comment: Sérgio, inseri o código acima e está funcionando.

Comment: @RRV boa! fico contente de ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque você está pegando o valor do `a` através do id, e todos os seus `a`s tem o mesmo id (o que é péssimo, o id deve ser único). Você está adicionando o evento ao elemento em si, então pode se referir ao próprio ao invés de procurá-lo pelo id. Remova os ids do html e para fazer a requisição faça assim:

```
$("#consult").on("click", ".link-form-delegation", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: Juliano, o `this` aí não vai funcionar. Dentro do `.ajax()` o `this` está noutro escopo. Altere para `var self = this;` e depois use `$(self)` dentro do ajax.

Comment: Tem razão @Sergio, escrevi a resposta meio correndo e deixei esse detalhe passar. Obrigado!